# Computation of Colored HOMFLY Polynomials

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am trying to understand the colored HOMFLY polynomials. The theoretic description Anna Aiston gave in her [PhD thesis](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/%7Esu14/papers/aistonthesis.pdf) is really nice, but what about the computation?

I would like to understand the [knots-quivers correspondence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04017.pdf), so I would like to learn how one can compute the $S^r$-colored HOMFLY polynomials. How can the $S^r$-colored HOMFLY polynomials $\overline{P}_K$ of a given knot $K$ be computed? For example, in the easiest cases of the unknot or the trefoil, is there a certain way how to compute the formulas as stated in the paper about the knots-quivers correspondence?

Comment: I think you linked the wrong paper for knots-quivers correspondence. Did you mean to link this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04017?

I want to thank you for bringing this knot-quiver correspondence to my attention!! I definitely am going to learn more about it. That being said, I do not believe that this correspondence has yet proven to be useful when trying to compute some colored HOMFLY polynomial. Calculating the colored HOMFLY polynomial is very tough, see (4.3) of https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/2013/931830/ and then the following examples of some special case calculations

Comment: (4.4) of the last paper I linked is a formula for computing the colored HOMFLY of the unknot. There is another paper that is very similiar to this one where the same formulas are obtained by different methods, although I can't find that paper at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Sorry, I corrected that.

Comment: The correspondence basically says that the generating function of the colored HOMFLY polynomials of a knot can be brought into a certain form which is equal to the generating function of a quiver (after a change of variables). In case of the unknot (section 5.1), the authors give a formula for the colored HOMFLY polynomials but do not explain how they can be calculated. And I am wondering how they got this formula. How can I compute that?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on mathoverflow.com.  Someone there might have an answer for you.